# Building a simple mp3 music player

Tags: audio-player

It is possible for me to write a simple mp3 music player? If yes, how should I go about building it? Are there any online resources that can help?

Comment: What language/platform do you have in mind ?

Comment: do you want something that can play and mp3 on a webpage, or do you want to program an actual mp3 player that you can run on your system (like the windows media player or itunes)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be the basis of creating a Flash based MP3 player: http://www.macloo.com/examples/audio_player/

Your question is a little too vague to warrant explicitly stating which language you should use.

^_^

Answer (score 3):

This has already been done and the is available on Google Code as [Damn Small Media Player](http://code.google.com/p/dsmp/).

Its built on C++ and the player just takes up only **716KB** of space and it is a simple download and use software. No Installers etc.

It has a features like:

> 1. Play Mp3s
> 2. Have a playlists, retain it and ability to add all files to the player
>      at once.
> 3. Multi-platform code.
> 4. Playlist Queue
> 5. Search

Comment: wow thanks, I think it would be useful

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `<audio>` HTML tag along with some simple JavaScript to create a nice music player that can seek and do all the things a normal player can. That is the best option, as it's the standard, supported in most browsers including those without Flash, and doesn't have the insecurity, instability and unnecessary  kludge of Flash.

Answer (score 1):

Yea , the process is pretty simple. Have you studied Data Compression? All you need is a program which takes a file stream from the input - your mp3 file, decompresses it according to the given bitrate using mp3. Google for the algorithm. There are readymade snippets for huffman decoding etc. and writes this decoded stream to your audio driver. You dont need to understand the algorithm , just implement it

Comment: thank you. Are there any tutorials that I could follow?

Comment: I like the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want to build a stand alone mp3 player, Drop a TMediaPlayer component on a Delphi form and take it from there ;)