# playing songs in html using hyperlink

Tags: html

this is the code i m using to play songs

```
<a href="http://southgreenvillecoc1.org/BeEncouragedByWhatYouKnow4-25-2010am.wma" 
    style=" text-decoration:none; color:#404040;" target="_blank">
        “Be Encouraged by What You Know”</a>
```

what do i need to do to play the song??? the link gets redirected to a different server....anything I need to embed??

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Flash-based MP3 player instead of WMA. The big advantage is that they work across browsers (of course, obviously, they need Flash installed).

Links to good players:

- [Building a simple mp3 music player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872852/building-a-simple-mp3-music-player)
- [embeddable flash based mp3 player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415889/embeddable-flash-based-mp3-player)

note that you'll need permission from the copyright holders / producers / authors to embed music like this.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways of embedding a WMA file. Here is a link explaining how to do so: http://www.mediacollege.com/video/format/windows-media/streaming/embed.html

> The example below shows the code for embedding a Windows Media file. Note that it uses two tags:   and . This is to enable maximum browser compatibility.You will need to set the file name (and other attributes if required) for both tags. Use true or false for the  tag, 1 or 0  for the  tag.

Comment: This is going to work on Windows only, though, and needs Media Player installed. Two big cons IMO.