# How to code a simple music player?

Tags: javascript, html, css, audio-player

I'm not sure why my last question got deleted, but ill try to go into more depth this time.

I am looking for code to make a music player that features:

- volume slider/adjuster
- has a playlist queue of songs (so like if youre listening to track 1, right under it, there will be a menu that says track 2, track 3, etc and if you click on track 3, it'll change to the corresponding track)
- has control butons (play, pause, stop, ff, rewind)

I can always have an individual music player for each of my 8 songs but I think it would be much easier to have one music player for all the songs. I dont know if this can be made in HTML/CSS (I'm new to coding), but it would be great; I just want to be able to get this to work.

Comment: Hi Anon, your question probably got deleted because StackOverflow is not a place to solicit other people to write code for you. It's more a site for fixing bugs in code you've already written.

Comment: This question is way too broad. Often when a question gets deleted there is a good reason to.

Comment: oh ok. I am just really frustrated because i've been trying to find multi-song players and i can't really find any. I  could always do the way I mentioned above, but I thought that there has to be an easier way that looks nicer as well

Comment: to the person above, this one didn't get deleted....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872852/building-a-simple-mp3-music-player

Comment: When you ask a question you need to be more specific as to what you want (i.e. if you are looking for libraries to help you with that, having some specific issue with your code, looking for tutorials - although this one you should probably use Google for). Please read the FAQ to find out what makes [a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) and what kind of questions you [should avoid](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask).

Comment: @user1594170 That's also not a very good question. Maybe it was back then (2010)? I don't know. The fact that that question exists doesn't make your question a good fit for SO as per [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 9):

You could try http://schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2. It's an HTML5 audio player with a nice fallback to Flash (as option).

Comment: You can have the rep for it. I'm a nice guy :)

Comment: I was just about to suggest the same thing :-p It's a good cross-browser sound player that uses Flash as a fallback for non-HTML5 compliant browsers. The examples should help get you started.